# Nginx timing out while trying to proxy from wibble

Tags: nginx, tcl

We have an application written in TCL and served using the [wibble web server](https://github.com/makr/wibble).  It is horrible and I want to put nginx infront of it so I can proxy paths like `/assets` to an asset server like sprockets, and `/help` to a gollum server or somesuch.

Wibble is running on port 8080, nginx is running on port 80, and the asset server is running on port 9292 (output from `netstat -tulpna` shown below):

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27599/nginx     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1536/tclsh8.6
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9292            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28941/rack
```

The OS is Debian so the config file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/site` is linked in the `sites-enabled` (the only linked file) directory and nginx has been restarted.

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name localhost;

  location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   proxy_read_timeout 120;
  }

  location /images {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292/images/;
  }

  location /css {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292/stylesheets/;
  }

  location /js {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292/javascripts/;
  }

}
```

The problem is when I run nginx and navigate to port 80, the asset server does it's job fine but the wibble server never replies causing nginx to give the `upstream timed out` error in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` (The server is 192.168.3.127 and I am 192.168.3.90):

```
2014/07/07 12:07:29 [error] 27601#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx-status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/nginx-status", host: "localhost"
2014/07/07 12:07:59 [error] 27601#0: *3 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 192.168.3.90, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "192.168.3.127"
2014/07/07 12:10:00 [error] 27601#0: *3 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 192.168.3.90, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host: "192.168.3.127"
2014/07/07 12:10:34 [error] 27601#0: *7 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx-status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/nginx-status", host: "localhost"
```

There is also these lines in `/var/log/nginx/access.log`:

```
192.168.3.90 - - [07/Jul/2014:12:06:19 +1200] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2014:12:07:29 +1200] "GET /nginx-status HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
192.168.3.90 - - [07/Jul/2014:12:07:59 +1200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Hangon, why is it trying to get this non-existant `/nginx-status` URI?  The wibble server is running on port 8080.

If I stop the wibble server, and load up a simple python server on the same port (8080) it works great!

I can still access the wibble server by going to `http://192.168.3.127:8080` and even by doing `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080` on the server it prints out the correct HTML.

**Why is wibble not replying to nginx but is replying to a browser and curl?**

(I'm in the process of trying to get wibble to output logs)

Answer (score 1):

After getting wibble to dump it's request object, I found that the HTTP version was being set to 1.0, although this didn't seem to affect `curl -0` from getting the HTML out.

**After upgrading nginx to the latest version everything works.**